# I am trying to build apk from flutter but when I run the command it gives me following warning Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build apk from flutter but when I run the command it gives me following warning
**charts_flutter-0.12.0/lib/src/chart_container.dart:209:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type **

I'ts from charts_flutter package I have used for rendering charts.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to null operation check which is irrelevant in current

Go to your flutter sdk folder,
search chart_container.dart
check your console, wherever you are getting error, search and remove ! sign,
errors should be gone.

https://github.com/google/charts/pull/739